# AWK sort rows/lines numerically for blocks of numbers

Tags: sorting, awk

I have a text file:

```
aa 
80,143
60,312
50,123
20,14
bb
cc
80,163
60,132
50,23
20,48
```

I wish to sort the rows from the smallest number to the largest everytime a block of numbers were found...

The expected result should look like:

```
aa 
20,14
50,123
60,312
80,143
bb
cc
20,48
50,23
60,132
80,163
```

How can the sort function be called to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you so much for editing the table for me! It was not very obvious how to have it done in the text box...

Comment: No problem. So what happens if the first number is the same one two lines?

Comment: THINK about the input you posted. You know there's alphabetic and numeric sorting, right? And in one of them `11` comes before `2` while in the other `11` comes after `2`? So why make your sample input data such that every leading number is the same number of digits so if we used the wrong sort method it'll look like it works and show no cases where 2 lines have the part before the comma identical so you need to go to the digits after the comma to resolve the relative order? [edit] your question to at least include something like `5,21` and `5,22` and `5,110` in one block.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps easiest is decorate/sort/undecorate approach with `awk` and friends

```
$  awk '{if(!/[0-9,]/) {c++;d=0} else {d=1} print c "." d "," $0}' file |
   sort -nt, | 
   cut -d, -f2-

aa
20,14
50,123
60,312
80,143
bb
cc
20,48
50,23
60,132
80,163
```

Comment: That will fail if/when there aren't always the same number of leading digits. Try changing the first `60` to `6`. Also, for this idiom you should use tabs instead of commas as the OFS from awk since that's the default separator for sort and cut and so you then don't need to use `-t` and `-d` respectively (though you're not actually using separate fields in sort in this case so the `-t,` isn't doing anything).

Comment: I have to apologise for being an absolute newbie here. I have put down the code into the windows cmd command window and I am getting error messages saying '-nt,The system cannot find the file specified.' and 'Cut is not recognisable as an internal or external command, operable programme or batch file.' Is this because I am not calling the method 'sort' and 'cut' in the correct format?

Comment: these are unix commands, in windows I think you should use cygwin or something similar. I'm not sure if/how windows version of `awk` works.  You can implement the complete command within an `awk` script as well.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) language has an [`awk` macro](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC) which implements the Awk paradigm in TXR Lisp syntax, and semantics.

A possible solution looks like this:

```lisp
;; sort list of (integer string) by the integer, ascending,
;; then extract the list of strings from the sorted result,
;; and dump it as a list of lines with tprint.

(defun sort-dump (num-rec-pairs)
  (tprint [mapcar second [sort num-rec-pairs < first]]))

;; Awk job

(awk (:begin (set fs "," ofs ","))           ;; set up I/O field separators
     (:let list)                             ;; bind local variable "list"

     ;; if we have two fields ...
     ((= nf 2) (mf int-str)                  ;; map string fields to integers
               (push (list [f 0] rec) list)) ;; push (field rec) pair to list

     ;; if we have one field ...
     ((= nf 1) (sort-dump list)              ;; dump the list
               (set list nil)                ;; clear the list
               (prn))                        ;; print current record

     (:end (sort-dump list)))                ;; dump list at end of awk job
```

Run:

```
$ txr sort.tl data
aa 
20,14
50,123
60,312
80,143
bb
cc
20,48
50,23
60,132
80,163
```

Comment: @karakfa Newly developed ~210 LOC: http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/share/txr/stdlib/awk.tl

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the sample input you provided and will work for the more interesting input you didn't provide (see my comment under your question):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function prtArr(        a,b) {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (a in arr) {
        for (b in arr[a]) {
            print a, b
        }
    }
    delete arr
}
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
/^[0-9,]+$/ { arr[$1][$2]; next }
{ prtArr(); print }
END { prtArr() }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
aa
20,14
50,123
60,312
80,143
bb
cc
20,48
50,23
60,132
80,163
```

The above uses GNU awk 4.* for true multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have GNU awk 4 on the PC. So there are error messages saying, illegal statement at source line in function prtArr... It's just the basic awk that I am using... Could you please advise if you have any suggestions on how to sort 4 rows every 5th row if that's simpler to deal with?

Comment: It's not simpler to deal with. Just get GNU awk 4.0 or later, you're missing a TON of extremely useful functionality without it. If you're on Windows then install/use cygwin to make your life much easier in general and GNU awk 4 will come with that.